# Sum of multiples of 3 and 5 MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If we list all the natural numbers up to `10` that are multiples of `3` or `5`, we get `3`, `5`, `6`, `9` and `10`. The sum of these multiples is `33`.

Write a function called `sum3and5muls` that returns the sum of all
the unique multiples of `3` or `5` up to `n`, where `n` is a positive integer and the only input argument of the function.

Here is attempt, but it is not working correctly for `n=1000` or bigger

```
function total_mults = sum3and5muls(n)

    N3  = 0:3:n;
    N5  = 0:5:n;
    N15 = 0:15:n;

    v  = N3(:)
    w  = N5(:)
    x  = sum(N15(:));

    sum_mults3 = sum(v);
    sum_mults5 = sum(w);

    total_mults = sum_mults3 + sum_mults5 - x;

end
```

Comment: Did you literally copy pasted your homework?

Comment: How are you determining that it's not working correctly? (It is)

Comment: define "not correctly". Can you give expected vs. actual outputs?

Answer (score 1):

That solution...scales pretty badly. Think about it: if you'd want to compute that for `N = 4294967295`, how much memory would you need?

```
<0:3:N>  = 1431655765 elements
<0:5:N>  = 858993459 elements
<0:15:N> = 286331153 elements
------------------------------- + 
2576980377 elements 
64-bit double precision 
------------------------------- × 
19.2 GB
```

That's a bit silly. Let's think differently:

```
function total_mults = sum3and5muls(n)

    assert(isinteger(n),...
           [mfilename ':datatype_error'],...
           'Input ''n'' expected to be integer.');

    total_mults = 0;
    for m = 1:n
        if mod(m,3)==0 || mod(m,5)==0;
            total_mults = total_mults + m; end
    end

end
```

which consumes only a handful of bytes of RAM. But, this is still kinda really silly. Let's put those gray cells to work a bit harder:

```
function total_mults = sum3and5muls(n)

    S = @(m) m*(m+1)/2;  
    total_mults = 3*S(floor(n/3)) + 5*S(floor(n/5)) - 15*S(floor(n/15));

end
```

which is starting to look professional. But, let's not stop there and pretend we really know about performance aspects, numerical artefacts like overflow, etc.:

```
function total_mults = sum3and5muls(n)

    fn3  = floor(n./3);
    fn5  = floor(n./5);
    fn15 = floor(fn5./3);

    fo3 = 1./fn3;
    fo5 = 1./fn5;

    total_mults0 = round(0.5 * fn3 * fn5 * ( ...
                 3*fn3*fo5      +  3*fo5      + ...
                 5*fn5*fo3      +  5*fo3      - ...
        fn15 * (15*fn15*fo3*fo5 + 15*fo3*fo5)   ...
        ))

end
```